# cv::bitwise_xor in JavaCV

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

My question may seem silly to some people. But I couldn't find any answer on the internet. 
Is there any equivalent function in JavaCv to the OpenCV function `cv::bitwise_xor(Mat,Mat,Mat)`? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [wiki](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/wiki/WhereIsFeatureXOfOpenCV) of JavaCV:

> If your favorite feature X of OpenCV has both a C API and a C++ API, JavaCV only maps the C API.

From the [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#bitwise-xor)

> C++: `void bitwise_xor(InputArray src1, InputArray src2, OutputArray dst, InputArray mask=noArray())`
>
> C: `void cvXor(const CvArr* src1, const CvArr* src2, CvArr* dst, const CvArr* mask=NULL)`

So (although not tested) I would expect it's called `cvXor`.